# Use GCloud Logs value as data point in metric

Tags: graph, gcloud, metrics, google-cloud-monitoring

I have an import in Google Appengine that runs once per day. This import produces several log entries in this format:

```
Imported N entries for type X
Imported M entries for type Y
...
```

I want to view that data in the metrics explorer so I can see the number of imported records per type per day in a graph.

I can create a logs based metric and extract the number and the type. But I can not figure out how I can tell the metric to use the number of the log as the value for the graph. I can only get it to count the number of log entries.

Edit:
To further clarify, these are example lines of my log:

```
Imported 15095 data for xxx on 2020-12-23
Imported 4784 data for yyy on 2020-12-23
```

My goal is to have a graph that would show the values on the y-axis and the date on the x-axis. So in this example, one line for `xxx` with a value of `15095` and one line for `yyy` with a value of `4784`.

I already extracted the relevant data as labels from the log.
I tried counter and distribution metrics, and different aggregations etc. but couldn't get what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

To view that data in the metrics explorer it is necessary to create a user-defined (logs-based) metric first and then use this metric to create a graph on Metrics Explorer.

You should define what type of metric you need, you can use `counter` or `distribution`.
Once you have defined this you could use one of the following guides:
[Creating a distribution metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/distribution-metrics#create-distribution)
[Creating a counter metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/counter-metrics#creating_a_counter_metric)

There is only a difference in the process when you need to select the type, but basically you need to follow the next steps to create it.

1. Go to [Logs Viewer](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?_ga=2.94190621.1678639349.1608561231-549298192.1605204650&_gac=1.263373566.1607379213.CjwKCAiAwrf-BRA9EiwAUWwKXs96xT84WhL0QBiVkLmROl1-j7OMiZgF9_fG3wrg7DyO4b74YpHFjRoCjlcQAvD_BwE), if you are in Logs Explorer and  when you click on create metric it will load the Legacy Logs Viewer:

[image]

2. You need to fill out the Metric Editor form and in this step you can choose between  `counter` or `distribution` types of metrics.

[image]

Once you have your user-defined metric created go to the Google Cloud's operations suite Logging > [Logs-based metrics page](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/metrics?_ga=2.94182429.1678639349.1608561231-549298192.1605204650&_gac=1.151225035.1607379213.CjwKCAiAwrf-BRA9EiwAUWwKXs96xT84WhL0QBiVkLmROl1-j7OMiZgF9_fG3wrg7DyO4b74YpHFjRoCjlcQAvD_BwE) in the Cloud Console and under User-defined Metrics you will see your new metric.

Each table row has a **menu**  that contains the [option](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics#logs-based_metrics_interface) to View in Metrics Explorer

[image]

Then will be able to you build your charts on [Metrics Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/metrics-explorer)

[image]

You could also check the following documentation, that describes how to choose the data to display and also how to display that chosen data when using Metrics Explorer: [Selecting metrics when using Metrics Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/metrics-selector)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! I already have the metrics, I tried a counter and a distribution metric but still couldn't get the results I wanted.I added more details to my initial question

Comment: I understand that you already have the metrics and the data needed, So I think you might find useful the following link [Choosing how to display the data](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/metrics-selector#select_display) or [Filtering and aggregation: manipulating time series](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/aggregation)